# Is this Java compiler error or correct statement?

Tags: java

Few days ago, I made a typo in java code but it compiled and worked well. (though the result is strange.)

My code is:

```
public  static  void    main(String args[])  {
    String  strOut;
    char    cSEP = '|';
    String  sSEP = "|";

    strOut = "AA" + cSEP + "BB";    // Correct assignment
    System.out.println(strOut);     // The result is "AA|BB". This is OK.

    strOut = "AA" + + cSEP + "BB";  // No Error : no token between two +
    System.out.println(strOut);     // The result is "AA124BB"

    strOut = "AA" + + sSEP + "BB";  // This is compiler error !!!
    System.out.println(strOut);
}
```

I cannot find why the 2nd assignment is not error and 124 is printed. (Of course, '|' is 124 in ASCII code. But why "124", not "|" ?)

Is this compiler bug? Or correct java syntax that I did not know yet ?

Comment: a char, like any other primitive, can be used as a numeric value. a String can't. I don't see any bugs here.

Comment: @Stultuske *like any other primitive*: except `boolean`? Or is there a context in which booleans can be used as numeric values that I don't know...

Comment: @ernest_k I misspoke: like most other primitives :)

Comment: @Stultuske and there I was rushing to use `+true` (it means "really true!", right?).

Comment: @AndyTurner to all those who automatically assume that two positives can't possibly make a negative .... "Yeah, right!" :)

Comment: I might add a check for this to [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between a `String` and a `char` is significant. some numeric operators, when applied on a `char`, turns the `char` into an `int` (this is called [unary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)). On the other hand, only the *binary* `+` operator is defined for `String`s.

In the second and third line of your code, the expression is parsed like this:

```
strOut = "AA" + (+ cSEP) + "BB";
```

The unary `+` operator, when applied on a `char`, turns the whole expression into an `int` through unary numeric promotion. The value is equal to the encoded value of the character. So the expression becomes:

```
strOut = "AA" + 124 + "BB";
```

which is valid.

But if `cSEP` were to be replaced with `sSEP`:

```
strOut = "AA" + (+ sSEP) + "BB";
```

The Java compiler doesn't know what `+ sSEP` means. The `+` unary operator is not defined for `String`!

Answer (score 4):

This is normal Java (expression) syntax.  In the expression:

```
"AA" + + cSep
```

the second `+` is the unary `+` operator which applies to (only) numeric types.  The `char` type is a numeric type in Java.

Note that unary `+` has a higher precedence than binary `+` so the above is equivalent to:

```
"AA" + ( + cSep )
```

But the expression:

```
"AA" + + sSep
```

is illegal because the unary `+` operator is **not** defined for `String`.

---

But what does `"AA" + + cSep` actually do?

Well the unary `+` operator performs a *unary numeric promotion* which converts the `char` to an `int`.  In context, it is equivalent to:

```
"AA" + ((int) cSep)
```

which is in turn equivalent to:

```
"AA" + Integer.toString((int) cSep)
```

That means that there will be a decimal number following the `AA` rather than a pipe character.

References:

- [JLS 15.15.3 Unary Plus Operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3)
- [JLS 15.18.1 String Concatenation Operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)
- [JLS 5.6.1 Unary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)

Answer (score 0):

It is correct java syntax. In java if we apply + unary operator on a character then it convert that character into it's unicode value.
like +'a' then it will convert it into 97 because unicode value of
character 'a' is 97.

so in your case 
strOut = "AA" + + cSEP + "BB";
       = "AA" + + '|' + "BB";

+'|' so this '|' will be converted into it's unicode value and unicode value of '|' is 124.

on String we cann't apply unary + operator so in this case
 strOut = "AA" + + sSEP + "BB";
you are getting error